# Annotate response of query based on week number

Tags: django, django-models

I have a query like this using the Django ORM:

```
query_set.annotate( metrics
    ).annotate(
        ....blah blah....
    ).annotate(title=Concat('date__year', Value('*'), 'date__month'))
```

I expect the title field to be like `2019-05` or similarly week number (`__week`) of the year such as `2019-30` that means the 30th week of 2019.

Comment: What is is showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use such lookups. Django expects field names. We can however perform the extraction earlier, like:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat, ExtractYear, ExtractMonth

query_set.annotate(
    dyear=ExtractYear('date'),
    dmonth=ExtractMonth('date'),
    title=Concat('dyear', Value('*'), 'dmonth')
)
```

Note however that the formatting will not add leading zeros, so it will be `2019-5`, instead of `2019-05`. Since [django-2.1](/questions/tagged/django-2.1) for example, you can use [**`LPad`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#lpad) for that:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat, ExtractYear, ExtractMonth, LPad

query_set.annotate(
    dyear=ExtractYear('date'),
    dmonth=LPad(ExtractMonth('date'), 2, Value('0')),
    title=Concat('dyear', Value('*'), 'dmonth')
)
```

but it of course makes it more complex.

You can extract the week number as well:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat, ExtractYear, ExtractWeek

query_set.annotate(
    dyear=ExtractYear('date'),
    dweek=ExtractWeek('date'),
    title=Concat('dyear', Value('*'), 'dweek')
)
```

That being said, if you do not plan to do filtering with that title, it might be better to do the rendering part at the Django layer. Python has better tooling for date formatting, furthermore by transfering `date` objects, you can make comparisons, and do all types of arithmetic with these. The main task of a database is to effectively store and retrieve information, not do proper formatting of that information.

Comment: did you actually try the query with LPad, because I tried it out, and it doenst seem to work for me. Any idea why? `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function lpad(double precision, integer, unknown) does not exist`